# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'background.calc_rc'; 'background' is not a package

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

So I've been working on a calculator GUI on pyqt5. I've installed Pyqt5 and even run "pip install background" on cmd and installed it on pycharm as well. Even with the package in the virtual env , it shows the following error :

ile "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\caclulator\main.py", line 10, in 
import background.calc_rc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'background.calc_rc'; 'background' is not a package.

I've tried all pip commands. Removing this one line executes the program successfully , but the GUI interface does not pop up. Please help.

Comment: What is `background`? That's not a PyQt package. Did you try to load some images in Designer and saved the resource file in a folder named "background"?

Comment: Yes I did , but i removed it and started it afresh without any background . My problem is that the GUI window does not pop up even if I don't use any backgrounds - in short it does not pop at all even if i do everything i can.

Comment: What window? Does the program start at all or does it crash? Please provide a [mre].